# Python - Polar plot without grid, tick labels and outer main circle(boundary)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to hide/turn off the boundary circle for polar plots in matplotlib? I have already applied `ax.grid(False)`, `ax.set_yticklabels([])` and `ax.set_xticklabels([])`.

```
r = np.arange(0,20 , 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.arange(0, 20, 0.01)
f2 = np.vectorize(cos)
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.plot(theta,(0)+(0)*(f2(theta)))
plt.show()
```

I want to remove the outer black circle.

[image: Click here for the Image.]

Comment: yes! it worked.

Comment: `ax.axis("off")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will just need to add the following code:

```
ax.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)
```

Comment: yes! it worked.